# Render function not working correctly inside views

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

This is my controller code:

```
     def index(conn, _params) do
       customers =  Repo.all(Customer)
       render conn, "index.json", customers: customers  
     end
```

This is the code inside Customer Views

```
 def render("index.json", %{customers: customers}) do
  %{
   data: render_many(customers, CustomerAdminView, "customer.json"),
  }
end 

  def render("customer.json", %{customer: customer}) do   
   %{
     id: customer.id,
     user: customer.user,
     billing_contact: customer.billing_contact

    }
  end
```

This will throw internal server error.
In the phoenix view documentation my code is identical to the example they provided. It works if I change `index.json` code to this:

```
def render("index.json", %{customers: customers} = assigns) do
 %{
  data: render_many(customers, CustomerAdminView, 
  "customer.json", assigns),
  }
end
```

Why would it work with render/4 and not render/3?

Comment: Can you show the error that you are getting in the console?

Comment: its internal server error code 500

Comment: I'm going to need something more specific. Phoenix will output an error and tell what went wrong and where. If you can get us that, I'm sure we can give you more information.